# How to run a Eloquent query from terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, laravel, ruby-on-rails-4, laravel-5

In Ruby On Rails, I can run:

```
rails c -e development
```

then, from terminal I can access models like:

```
Post.find(4)
```

Is this possible in Laravel? I need to debug by accessing models from terminal to run specific query, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tinker:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Then you can just call your model:

```
App\Posts::find(1);
```

Here's a good reference: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/280/interacting-with-your-application

Answer (score 0):

Open a SSH session, go to the project root and run this command:

```
php artisan tinker
```

Now you can run php commands as if you where writing a PHP code, example:

```
\App\Post::find(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start tinker session.

```
php artisan tinker
```

Example of request

```
\App\Post::all();
```